# Laravel: mkdir(): Permission denied - Nginx

Tags: nginx

Trying to upload a file with opening new folder.
But laravel returns error like below.

```
    $destinationPath = public_path() . $folderName;
    if(!is_dir(public_path().'/uploads')) {
      mkdir(public_path().'/uploads', 0755, true);
    }
    $mkdir = mkdir(public_path().'/uploads/'.$unique, 0755, true);
    $success = file_put_contents(public_path().'/uploads/'.$unique."/".$filename, $file);
```

I used;

```
sudo chown -R nginx:nginx public/uploads
sudo chown -R root:root public/uploads
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER public/uploads
```

But nothing changed.
What's wrong?

Is laravel's nginx user different? How can I learn?

Answer (score 1):

you should check the Nginx user inside your Nginx config file.it can be found at `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and likely set to `user www-data;`

Answer (score 0):

Try running the command

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data public/uploads
```

This command should work. If now let me know.